# Setting Default Content For TinyMCE Does Not Work In IE

Tags: internet-explorer, tinymce, tinymce-4

The following works well for Firefox and Chrome for setting default content... but NOT for IE

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
        function loadDefaultTinyMCEContent(){
            parent.tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('<p><a href=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/80930543?autoplay=1#t=0m6s\" rel=\"nofollow\">dfgdsfgd</a></p><p><img src=\"uploads/2/Koala.jpg\" alt=\"Koala.jpg\" /></p>');}
        </script>
```

I get the following error in the IE developer panel:

Unable to get property 'setContent' of udefined or null reference.

What could this mean? Here is my tinymce init

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    plugins: 'links link spellchecker lists paste snippet image moxiemanager table',
    theme: "modern",
    menubar: false,
    toolbar1: "links | unlink | image | table",
    toolbar2: " bold italic underline | bullist numlist | spellchecker | alignleft aligncenter alignright",
    //width: 600,
    height: 400,
    invalid_elements : "h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6",
    paste_as_text: true,
    object_resizing : false,
    advimagescale_max_width: 300,
    entity_encoding : "raw"

});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps not the exact answer you were after with regards to a possible IE bug you may have found. But you're probably better off loading your page with the textarea already containing the default html you want to use. As in:

```
<textarea>
   <p><a href=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/80930543?autoplay=1#t=0m6s\" rel=\"nofollow\">dfgdsfgd</a></p><p><img src=\"uploads/2/Koala.jpg\" alt=\"Koala.jpg\" /></p>
</textarea>
```

I do it this way and it seems to work fine for me in IE.

Comment: This works to some extent, except there are problems that need to be dealt with like escaping characters like apostrophe etc...

Comment: Yeah, point taken, sorry I just copied and pasted from your example